Why should Branch&Bound not terminate if the relaxation is an unbounded LP?
In my homework assignment there is a task which wants you to show that for specific integer programs Branch&Bound could run forever.
One could just choose the relaxation of the IP to be some kind of infinite diagonal stripe which doesn't have any integral points and choose c (from the objective $c^Tx$) to be parallel to the stripe.
Example:
$$max\{(1,1)\cdot x: 1 \leq -3x_1 + 3 x_2 \leq 2, \;(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{Z}^2\} $$
Notice that: $\{1 \leq -3x_1 + 3 x_2 \leq 2\} \cap \mathbb{Z}^2 = \emptyset$
What I assume to be the right answer is something along the lines: No matter if you cut the stripe horizontally or vertically, you will never find an integral solution and there will always be left an unbounded part of the stripe, so that Branch&Bound actually never terminates.
But does Branch&Bound really never stop? I mean shouldn't the Simplex Algo for the relaxation just return some kind of "Problem is unbounded, we are done" in the beginning so that we would actually terminate after one step?

An unbounded LP relaxation does not tell you whether the IP is unbounded, infeasible, or optimal, so you need to branch.

Do you maybe have an example for the case where the LP relaxation is unbounded but the IP has an optimal solution?

Consider a ray from the origin with irrational slope.

But if my polyhedron is rational (sorry, I forgot to mention that) then we have: LP relaxation infeasible or unbounded -> IP infeasible or unbounded. Is this right?
